# Check python/django library dependencies

Tags: python, django, pip

I have discovered that I have an installed library in my django app(as a dependecy for another one i think) and I want to know which package/library has introduced. How can I do that
the installed library is: `pathspec`

my `requirements.txt` file is:

```
Babel==2.4.0
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
django-admin-list-filter-dropdown==1.0.1
django-admin-sortable2==0.6.19
django-background-tasks==1.1.12
django-categories==1.5.4
django-ckeditor==5.3.1
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
django-filter==1.0.4
django-import-export==1.0.0
django-markdownx==2.0.22
django-object-actions==0.10.0
django-rest-auth[with_social]==0.9.2
django-simple-metatags==0.9.1
django-static-sitemaps==4.4.0
django-storages==1.5.2
django-taggit==0.22.2
django-taggit-helpers==0.1.4
Django==1.11.10
djangorestframework~=3.6.4
```

Comment: So you want to know which one lib in your requirements.txt depends on `pathspec`?

Comment: yes. which library has introduced the installation of `pathsepc`

Comment: It is difficult using `pip`, but you can use the only one fantastic tool `pipenv`. It can manage dependencies. Take a look: https://docs.pipenv.org/

Comment: [pip dependency tree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/)

Answer (score 0):

I have just cleaned up the virualenv. started one from scratch un run `pip install -r requirement.txt`, and took a look at the log. there one can see which package is installed/triggered by which one